# Automatic checking JSF (xhtml) files for correct syntax

Tags: java, maven, xhtml, jsf-2

is there a way check XHTML files for correct syntax?
I know [JSFUnit](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit), but this seems to be a little overkill for my needs. The test should be done during the project build process with maven, so a Maven plugin would be fine. A library is also ok. In general I want to check for some regular occurring runtime errors like this:

- Duplicate ids in view
- Unbalanced < > in the file
- CommandButton must be inside a form element
- ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any Maven based HTML Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139189/are-there-any-maven-based-html-validators)

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment to use the [xml-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) which can validate files against the schema. You need to put that into the correct lifecycle-phase of your maven build.