# Are there any Maven based HTML Validators

Tags: html, maven

I've got a project that contains a number of HTML files. As part of my Maven build process I'd like to run a validator across these files to make sure that:

1. The files are syntactically correct (for example checking that all opening tags have a coresponding closing tag)
2. The files conform to the coding guidelines

Can anybody recomend a good validator that would do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using [Sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/) with the 2 significant plugins as

1. [XML Plugin](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarxml.html)

This plugin enables analysis of XML files within Sonar.
Some common use cases are:

1. Validation of XHTML files against schemas provided by the W3C (strict, transitional, and others)
2. Validation of XML files against a provided XML schema
3. Validation of rules in XML files (ex: validate the Maven pom files against coding standards)

2 .[Web Plugin](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarweb.html)

The plugin provides static code analysis of web files within Sonar. Currently JSP and JSF are supported. Some initial support is provided for Ruby templating (erb files).

The following metrics are supported:

1. sizing (files, lines of code)
2. rules compliancy
3. complexity
4. duplication
5. comments

The plugin scans the following files by default: .xhtml, .jspf, .jsp. The file extensions are configurable.

The plugin imports the source code in Sonar, calculates measurements and scans the code for violations, duplications and complexity. The checks are configurable in the Sonar rules repository.

All of them are *open source*. Anyhow the Sonar also provides the commercial plugin named [Web(HTML, JSP)](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/web/) as well.

Comment: @KarlRichter Thank you very much for mentioning. I've updated the dead URL already. So far the analysis is done via the SonarQube server, you may see further information at https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven

Answer (score 0):

There is now also a maven plugin for the Nu HTML Checker (https://validator.github.io) that works offline: https://github.com/validator/maven-plugin. Disclaimer: I'm the author of the maven plugin.